# Read in CSV files horizontally using csvreader in python

Tags: python, file, csv

According to my research, the csvreader reads in data that is in a format like this

```
Name,Date,Job
John,3/14/2019,Doctor
Susan,3/14/2019,Cashier
```

However, the data that I have stored is formatted like this

```
Name,John,Susan,
Date,3/14/2019,3/14/2019
Job,Doctor,Cashier
```

Is there a way to get the CSV reader to read it in this way? I am currently doing it without it but its quite tedious when new lines show up between the commas.

Comment: Why dont you store it as a normal csv?

Comment: @balderman It's not my data it's the way my company stored it in an excel doc and then when you convert it to a csv file for easy reading it is saved like that.

Comment: Are you trying to transpose? Somthing like `list(zip(*reader))` will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are trying to use the csv library, but this is easy with pandas and the transpose operation.

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('horizontal.csv', index_col=0)

```
>>> df
           John      Susan
Name                      
Date  3/14/2019  3/14/2019
Job      Doctor    Cashier

>>> df.T
Name        Date      Job
John   3/14/2019   Doctor
Susan  3/14/2019  Cashier
```

Answer (score 0):

Try (not_csv.txt is a file that contains the data you have provided)

The data structure that is created by zip is a list of tuples.

Read about zip [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip).

```
with open('not_csv.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
    for idx, entry in enumerate(data):
        if idx == 0:
            names = entry.split(',')[1:]
        elif idx == 1:
            dates = entry.split(',')[1:]
        elif idx == 2:
            jobs = entry.split(',')[1:]
merged_data = zip(names, dates, jobs)

print(merged_data)
```

Output

```
[('John', '3/14/2019', 'Doctor'), ('Susan', '3/14/2019', 'Cashier')]
```